# Can I generate all possible binary strings with specified number of bit flips in python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a program, where the input is a binary string with arbitrary length, as well as the number of bit flips desired, and the output is all the possible strings with the specified number of bit flips (in a list). For example, if the input is `'110'` and `2`, the output is `['000','101','011']`. I'm new to python and didn't find any similar programs. I really have no idea how I can do that. Could anyone give me some hints? Many thanks for the help!!

Comment: It's OK to be new and to be trying - but you'll have to share what you tried and explain where you got stuck. StackOverflow won't write your code for you, but people here can help if have trouble getting something to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer xor version of Ice Griffin's answer.

```
from itertools import combinations
 
input_bits = '110'
flip_count = 2
# get all available single bit flips
flips = [1 << i for i in range(len(input_bits))]
combs = combinations(flips, flip_count)
 
# flip given bit string
def flip(bit_str, comb):
    n = int(bit_str, 2) ^ sum(comb)
    return f'{n:0{len(bit_str)}b}'

# implement combination
for comb in list(combs):
    flipped = flip(input_bits, comb)
    print(flipped)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination algorithm to generate all possible cases.

```
from itertools import combinations
 
input_bits = '110'
flip_count = 2
# get all available flip positions
flip_positions = [_ for _ in range(len(input_bits))]
combs = combinations(flip_positions, flip_count)
 
# flip given bit string
def flip(bit_str, comb):
    bit_arr = [_ for _ in bit_str]
    for i in comb:
        if bit_arr[i] == '0':
            bit_arr[i] = '1'
        else:
            bit_arr[i] = '0'
    return ''.join(bit_arr)

# implement combination
for comb in list(combs):
    flipped = flip(input_bits, comb)
    print(flipped)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's very helpful:)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate directly on all possible 2**n numbers and find what you are looking for without using any library functions.

```py
s, k = map(str,input().split())
k = int(k)
n = len(s)
ans = []
for i in range(2**n):
    num = bin(i)[2:]
    num = "0" * (n - len(num)) + num
    if(num.count("1") == k):
        # Flip s at on positions of num
        res = ""
        for j in range(n):
            if(num[j] == "1"):
                res += str(1 - int(s[j]))
            else:
                res += s[j]
        ans.append(res)
print(*ans)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, that helps! :)